# Redirect .jpg to Html without Changing the extention of .jpg images on the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, redirect

This is what i am looking for

http://more-sky.com/data/out/2/IMG_21306.jpg

How it redirect to its parent page i.e (http://more-sky.com/WDF-21306.html)

This above link is redirecting from .jpg to .html but its still showing the images(.jpg)

For Example

I want to redirect

> www.domain.com/images/Apple.jpg

to

> www.domain.com/Apple.html

(Brief Explanation : Image  is on page **www.domain.com/Apple.html**. whenever anyone open **www.domain.com/images/Apple.jpg** it should redirect to **www.domain.com/Apple.html**)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a rule that makes a redirect to the correct page in your web server. For example if you are using Apache you can try using [rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)

Comment: But I want Dynamically.Suppose it will be 500 html pages.

Comment: Well in that case either you use regex in the redrection declaration or manually handle the redirection in the server pages of your web.